# Changing font-weight on the 5th characters inside text-input

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm curious to know if there is a way to change the font weight of a text-input value once someone types the 5th character and onwards using either css or jquery.

for example someone types "XXXX 9999" the letters xxxx has font-weight 400, after which 9999 has font-weight 600 on the same text-input. There should also be a space before the 5th character.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="input-label">Text Input </label>
      <label class="translation">translation</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Text" value="XXXX 9999">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no way to style parts of a text input differently. Either use `contentEditable`, or an overlay over `input`; both would need scripting to make it work. A third possibility would be to use two different text inputs (and optionally script the focus to change on keypress). A brilliant demonstration of the overlay technique is https://regex101.com/ where you are typing in an obscured text input, and the coloured representation of that input is shown over it. There was a lot of hard work put in there, though.

Comment: hi ilyas, this should be similar to what you want, https://jsfiddle.net/KennyChoy/7qbnz9re/37/, not perfect yet, still need to modify